# Speed up MongoDB Query Response | Discord Bot

Tags: mongodb, optimization, discord.py, pymongo

I didn't think this would be an issue, but as the database I am using continues to grow, I've noticed that the responses from my program are getting slower and slower (which makes sense, more stuff to look through to return).

Now my question is how would I be able to speed up the performance of my response because it takes quite some time to do the following as of right now:
I want to sort and return to the top 10 results from a query search, currently, my code looks something along the lines of:

```
alldocuments = self.bot.db.nameofdb.find()
alldocuments = list(map(lambda x: x["userId"], alldocuments ))
_documentCount = [(i, alldocuments.count(i)) for i in set(alldocuments)]
_documentCount.sort(key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
docCount = list(filter(lambda x: ctx.guild.get_member(int(x[0])), _documentCount))
        
        
i = 0
while i < 10:
     if not ctx.guild.get_member(int(docCount[i][0])):
          i+=1
          continue
     print(docCount[i][1]})
     i += 1
```

Some information:

Database consists of thousands of entries as follow:

```
Entry Ex. 1:
{
_id: 62338b6994b3773415bd7efc
uid: "849551661"
gacha_type: 100
item_id: ""
count: "1"
time: "2021-12-25 17:42:58"
name: "Magic Guide"
lang: "en-us"
item_type: "Weapon"
rank_type: "3"
id: "1640423160000228061"
userId: 738362958253522976
}

Entry Ex. 2
{

_id: 62338b6994b3773415bd7efe
uid: "849551661"
gacha_type: 100
item_id: ""
count: "1"
time: "2021-12-25 17:42:58"
name: "Noelle"
lang: "en-us"
item_type: "Character"
rank_type: "4"
id: "1640423160000227861"
userId: 738362958253522976

}
```

Now my database currently exists with over 100k of these entries, and I want to sort them by userId in the order of which "userId" has the greatest amount of entries.

A sample result should be something along the lines of:

```
1. 25k - userId
2. 15k - userId
3. 10k - userId
4. 8k - userId
5. 5k - userId
6. 1k - userId
7. 200 - userId
8. 100 - userId
9. 50 - userId
10. 25 - userId
```

where anyone with under 25 entries would just be ignored.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected result.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I have edited the post, please take a look when you can.

Comment: And what kind of result you like to get?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit well it says at the bottom, I want to get x amount of names from the greatest number of entries to least number of entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to give an answer without proper information (i.e. maybe 2-3 more sample input documents and sample result). However, could be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        location: "$location",
        name: "$name"
      },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { count: -1 } },
  { $limit: 10 }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using MongoDB, you're able to directly include those filters that you are applying into your query. This should impact your runtime by loading fewer data.

```py
documents = self.bot.db.nameofbd.find({"queryparam": True})
sorted_documents = documents.sort("queryparam": pymongo.DESCENDING)
```

Comment: Yeah but say the queryparam is a name for example, I want to sort the amount of entries each person has in the db from greatest to least. So if "Adam" has 10k documents in the db, and the next person has 5k, it should return 10k then 5k

Comment: Or even `sorted_documents  = self.bot.db.nameofbd.find({"queryparam": True}).sort("queryparam": pymongo.DESCENDING)`